# ARC forbids synthesizing a property with unspecified ownership or storage

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, compiler-errors, automatic-ref-counting

I've created a `@property` of `UIColor`,

```
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *color;
```

and then I tried to synthesize it:

```
@synthesize color = _color;
```

but I receive an error:

> ARC forbids synthesizing a property of Objective-C object with unspecified ownership or storage attribute

What does that mean?

All I'm trying to do is to create a property for a `UIColor` object which changes color.

Comment: You might have to give full class declaration and implementation as this seems valid. Storage by default in properties is strong unless it is a block in which you have to specify it manually as `copy`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Change your property declaration to:

`@property (nonatomic,strong) UIColor *color;`

so that ARC knows it should be retained.  This would have compiled without `strong` before ARC but it would be dangerous since the default was `assign` and the color would have been released unless it was retained elsewhere.

I would highly recommend the WWDC2011 video about ARC.

Comment: This is not required unless the property is a block in which case it has to be explicitly mentioned as `copy`. So the issue is something else.

Comment: @VikramRao, this question is 2.5 years old.  At the time that it was asked, synthesized properties were required to declare the storage class and the default was `assign`

Comment: @Brian Anyway, it'd be good to update your accepted answer, as people may see it via google. These devs, who don't know it, may think they need to write it explicitly. As for now this error is shown mostly with blocks, which needs to be `copy`. Objects are by default `strong`, primitive types like `BOOL`, `NSInteger` etc - `assign` and it's unlikely anyone can see this error with objects/primitive types.

Comment: @Vive Actually you don't need to declare blocks `copy` anymore - it's fine to declare them `strong` now. If the block has already been copied to the heap, `copy` has always behaved like `strong` (both just retained the block). If the block was still on stack though, `copy` used to copy it to heap while `strong` used to do nothing. The LLVM developers considered that a bug, regardless what Apple's documentation said and now `strong` behaves like `copy` if the block is on stack, just like `copy` behaves like `strong` if it's on heap - IOW it makes no difference anymore, only `weak` does.

Comment: @Brian Even at the time it was asked, your answer has still been wrong. It's true, the default prior to ARC used to be `assign`, but no storage class was required as if it was required, there would not have been a default at all. Default means "unless I say something else, take this". Not giving a storage class created an `assign` property. Maybe not what you wanted, but the compiler did not throw an error because of that. Why would applying default behavior be erroneous?

Comment: @Mecki, my answer was correct, but yeah my comment about required/default doesn't really make sense

Comment: @Brian You're right, I've just checked https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html and found section: `How do blocks work in ARC? Blocks “just work” when you pass blocks up the stack in ARC mode, such as in a return. You don’t have to call Block Copy any more.`. Thank you for the useful information, didn't notice it.

Comment: As @VikramRao mentioned, when you are specifiing block as a property, you have to explicitly put copy.. Thank you for this hint, should be highlighted more..

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify either `strong` or `weak` storage in the property declaration (next to `nonatomic`).

Comment: @WilliamSham you don't need to do it for all pointers, only for properties. Pointers in the local scope are strong references by default, but you can instruct ARC to treat a pointer as a weak reference by using __weak.

Comment: @JoePasq Not required to specify storage always. Check my comments in other answers and question.