# AFNetworking compilation errors

Tags: afnetworking

I'm new to AFNetworking earlier I was using ASIHTTPRequest and now I want to shift to AFNetworking after researching a lot on google. But now when I download the Library and want to look at the example project I'm facing errors in the code.

I just compiled and I got 13 errors, please have a look at the image below, any help will be greatly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 3):

the erros have nothing to do with AFNetworking, it's the Post.m file in your sample project. Have you declared the text and user properties in Post.h?

Comment: property (readonly) NSUInteger postID;
property (readonly) NSString *text;
property (readonly) User *user;  I have removed @ here before property because it doesn't allow me here anyways, one of the person at github told me 'Looks like your default ARC settings are not right'. So what does he mean?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460611/arc-forbids-synthesizing-a-property-with-unspecified-ownership-or-storage

Answer (score 1):

The example should run fine as it is provided as part of the AFNetworking script on github

These are the Requirement Notes for the AFNetworking project
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

> AFNetworking 1.0 and higher requires either iOS 5.0 and above, or Mac
>   OS 10.7 (64-bit with modern Cocoa runtime) and above.
>
> For compatibility with iOS 4.3, use the latest 0.10.x release.
>
> ARC
>
> AFNetworking uses ARC as of its 1.0 release.
>
> If you are using AFNetworking 1.0 in your non-arc project, you will
>   need to set a -fobjc-arc compiler flag on all of the AFNetworking
>   source files. Conversely, if you are adding a pre-1.0 version of
>   AFNetworking, you will need to set a -fno-objc-arc compiler flag.
>
> To set a compiler flag in Xcode, go to your active target and select
>   the "Build Phases" tab. Now select all AFNetworking source files,
>   press Enter, insert -fobjc-arc or -fno-objc-arc and then "Done" to
>   enable or disable ARC for AFNetworking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define properties of objects as unsafe_unretained/strong/weak/copy/retain/assign.